# Getting Manipulation point on the screen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, touch, screen-orientation

I'm making a phone app where I need to know where my touch manipulation point is on the screen. I've already set the Manipulation.container to a Viewbox which i can manipulate around. However I would like to get the manipulation relative to the screen, such that I can make some calculation between the viewbox and the point on the screen. Do I have to set my manipulation.container to something else or how do I get the point relative to the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A viewport controller should be used, and it enables the information through viewport property.